# Below code should stop after 3 retry and print the final output as false, but it is stuck in the first method call

Tags: java

context :
so the below code needs to be fixed which always enter in the recursion mode and fails to give the final output or do maximum 3 retries

```
// starting of the main java program    
public class RecursiveCall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean result = callingFirstMethod(0);
        System.out.println("Name = "+ result);
    }

// calling callingFirstMethod with a variable with tryCount as 0
    public static Boolean callingFirstMethod(int tryCount){
        final int maxRetries = 3;
        boolean successful = false;

// method call which fails in this method and always return false
        successful = divisonMethods();

// condition which should be tried only 3 times, need to fix that 
        while(tryCount < maxRetries && !successful){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (RuntimeException e){
                System.out.println("Exception Occured with Timer"+ e.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
// this is where recursion actually starts and in since it always fails and enter in the infinite loop 
//and trycount value never increases because in the first call itself it will never complete the loop and never increase the value in the trycount to 2.
            successful = callingFirstMethod( tryCount++);
        }
        return successful;
    }

// method which always returns false 
    public static Boolean divisonMethods(){
        if(5>6){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

context :
so the below code needs to be fixed which always enter in the recursion mode and fails to give the final output or do maximum 3 retries

Comment: Whenever the program enters callingFirstMethod() the tryCount is equal to 0. Then you start a while loop which is ended whenever tryCount gets equal to maxRetries. But the value in tryCount is always less than 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not understand recursion and in that case, it is best to avoid recursion and gather some experience first. It was proved that every recursion can be written as cycle and vice versa.

So in your case, we can just do this:

```
// starting of the main java program    
public class RecursiveCall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean result = callingFirstMethod(0);
        System.out.println("Name = "+ result);
    }

// calling callingFirstMethod with a variable with tryCount as 0
    public static Boolean callingFirstMethod(int tryCount){
        final int maxRetries = 3;
        boolean successful = false;

// method call which fails in this method and always return false
        successful = divisonMethods();

// condition which should be tried only 3 times, need to fix that 
        while(tryCount < maxRetries && !successful){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (RuntimeException e){
                System.out.println("Exception Occured with Timer"+ e.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
// this is where recursion actually starts and in since it always fails and enter in the infinite loop 
//and trycount value never increases because in the first call itself it will never complete the loop and never increase the value in the trycount to 2.
            successful = divisonMethods();
            tryCount++;
        }
        return successful;
    }

// method which always returns false 
    public static Boolean divisonMethods(){
        if(5>6){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Altough if you insist on recursion, you can. Also the recursion allows you to avoid the while-cycle

```
// starting of the main java program    
public class RecursiveCall {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean result = callingFirstMethod(0);
        System.out.println("Name = "+ result);
    }

// calling callingFirstMethod with a variable with tryCount as 0
    public static Boolean callingFirstMethod(int tryCount){
        final int maxRetries = 3;
        boolean successful = false;

// method call which fails in this method and always return false
        successful = divisonMethods();

// condition which should be tried only 3 times, need to fix that 
       if (tryCount < maxRetries && !successful){            
            successful = callingFirstMethod( tryCount + 1);
        }
        return successful;
    }

// method which always returns false 
    public static Boolean divisonMethods(){
        if(5>6){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Be careful when using `someVariable++` it will first use the variable and then increment it by 1. Unless you are 100% sure how that works, use this only as standalone command to increase something by +1. Do not use it in complex expressions.